# SVN Commit failled - Access is denied : 500 Internal Server error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, jdeveloper, visualsvn-server

I have recently moved my VisualSVN Server 2.5.2 to a new machine(from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2) in the same network moving the `/Repositories` directory from one machine to another (copy/paste).

I use Subversion from inside my JDeveloper installation 11.1.1.4 to keep track of my coding. The checkout functionality is working OK. When I try to commit something through JDeveloper I get the following error:

```
svn:Commit failled (details follow):
svn: Can't open file 'C:\Repositories\xxxxxxx\db\txn-current-lock': Access is denied.
svn: MKACTIVITY of '/svn/xxxxxxx/!svn/act/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx': 500 Internal Server Error(https://nameOfMyServer)
```

The commit is done using:

```
commit -m "" C:/JDeveloper/mywork/newRepo/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Filename.java
```

When i try to commit using TortoiseSVN (1.7.7 64bit) through a file System I get the following error :

```
Commit
Commit failed (details follow):
The POST request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line
 3: not well-formed (invalid token) (/svn/xxxxxxxxxxx/!svn/me)
```

The checkout also works fine using TortoiseSVN.

Please note that I have double-checked all permission in my repositories and the user I login as has all read/write privileges.

Comment: Solved.

Just Upgraded VisualSVNServer sosftware from 2.5.2 to 2.5.4 and now is working ok

Comment: You could also resolve the issue by checking the "automatically adjust permissions" in VisualSVN Server Manager settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just Upgraded VisualSVNServer sosftware from 2.5.2 to 2.5.4 and now is working ok. I am not sure exactly what the problem was. I have not tested the solution provided by **bahrep**. It could well be also a solution.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the VisualSVN Server service account (*'Network Service'* by default) lacks modify NTFS permissions to the repositories root folder (*'C:\Repositories'*) and it's childs.

You can also force the permissions through VisualSVN Server Manager.

[image: Automatically adjust permissions]

See [Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a PERMISSIONS issue.
Grant 777 permission to your repository folder on server.